# How to generate a empty block in dev chain on parity? like dev.period in geth?

Tags: mining, parity

I use config like this:

```
[parity]
mode="active"
chain = "dev"
base_path = "./data"
db_path = "./data/chains"
keys_path = "./data/keys"
identity = ""
light = false

[rpc]
disable = false
port = 8545
interface = "local"
cors = ["null"]
apis = ["all"]
hosts = ["all"]
server_threads = 10

[websockets]
disable = false
port = 8546
interface = "local"
origins = ["*"]
apis = ["all"]
hosts = ["all"]

[mining]
author = "00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72"
engine_signer = "00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72"
force_sealing = true
reseal_on_txs = "all"
reseal_min_period = 2000
reseal_max_period = 10000
min_gas_price = 20000000000
price_update_period = "10"
gas_floor_target = "4700000"

[network]
min_peers = 0
max_peers = 50

[account]
unlock = ["00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72"]
password = ["./pass"]
keys_iterations = 10240
```

in dev chain, parity will autogenerate a block when a transaction is sent. But I need it to generate a block every 15 sec, so that I can test the confirmation number of a transaction. In geth, i can set --dev.period=15 to fulfill my need. But in parity, i can not find a way. If really can't mine on dev chain, I might have to send a transaction every 10sec by myself. Any suggestions? Thanks!